# Count(*) an attribute from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

**Question:**
How would you display one field from an outer query and another from an inner subquery?

**My Problem:**
I need to display the names of actors AND how many movies each one has made (even if they haven't been in any) without any left or right joins.

```
Star(starnumb, starname)
MovStar(starnumb, mvnumb)
```

I previously displayed the information using a join;

```
SELECT starname, COUNT(movstar.starnumb) AS numMovies
```

The issue I have is the information for the amount of movies a star has acted in are inside the Movstar relation and the star's name is inside the Star relation.

```
SELECT starname, COUNT(*) AS numMovies
FROM star s
Where starnumb NOT IN
    (SELECT movstar.starnumb
    FROM movstar)
OR starnumb IN
(SELECT movstar.starnumb
    FROM movstar)
GROUP BY starname
ORDER BY numMovies DESC;
```

The code runs, but I can't get the right information to display inside the Count field;

```
SELECT starname, COUNT(*) AS numMovies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can correlate a subquery e.g. by comparing one of its columns with one of the columns from the outer query. And `count()` will give `0` if no matching records was found.

```
SELECT s.starname,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM movstat ms
               WHERE ms.starnumb = s.startnumb) nummovies
       FROM star s;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sticky Bit! I didn't realise I could do sub queries inside the Select clause.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't want to use join?

`SELECT s.starname, count(*) AS numMovies FROM star s LEFT JOIN movstar m ON m.starnumb = s.starnumb GROUP BY startname ORDER BY numMovies DESC`

should get you what you ask for if I understood it correctly.